# Windows Phone Inputscope - can't see Passwordbox when user is on TextBox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I have Textbox and Passwordbox inside StackPanel. When I am typing in Textbox I can't see whole PasswordBox (just 1/3 of it's height) so it's hard for user to change from Textbox to Passwordbox. When I am typing in PasswordBox I see Textbox and Passwordbox correctly.

How I can fix that?

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="50,0">
                    <Grid Height="72" Margin="0,0,5,5" Background="White">
                        <Controls:WatermarkTextBox WatermarkText="{Binding LocalizedResources.LoginWatermark, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"
                            x:Name="LoginEmail" InputScope="EmailUserName" BorderThickness="3" Foreground="#DE000000" FocusedForeground="#DE000000" BorderBrush="White" Background="#A5FFFFFF" CaretBrush="White"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Height="72" Margin="0,5,5,0" Background="White">
                        <Controls:WatermarkPasswordBox x:Name="LoginPassword" WatermarkText="{Binding LocalizedResources.PasswordWatermark, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"
                            Password="" Foreground="#DE000000" FocusedForeground="#DE000000" Background="#A7FFFFFF" BorderBrush="White" SelectionForeground="White" />
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and works fine for me! Can you post the entire XAML source code? Is the `ContentPanel` the root element of the visual tree or it's inside other container? Can you also specify if you're using third-party libraries? (in particular for those watermark controls)

Comment: Well it's working well if it's on top of the screen. If you put those Watermark Boxes at bottom you will notice that WP will set view at first Box and second will be cut in half. So far I didn't find any solution how to fix that, but what I do is storyboard which on focus at Box move them from bottom to middle and provide better accessibility.